# Cross platform converting

Tags: visual-studio, flash, mobile, cross-platform, actionscript-2

I'm about to start a fairly large project. I have about 10 different PC/MAC Flash(AS 2.0)/MDM Zinc software packages I have inherited from a previous programmer. They are a series of math educational applications that are all contained on numerous CDs which is pretty frustrating for our customers. I've been tasked with converting these applications into a digital medium with emphasis on iOS/Droid compatibility.

They don't want to ditch the flash because of the way it's written and compiled with MDM Zinc it would almost require a complete rewrite. Currently the customer installs the application using Disc 1 of their set and the application will pull the lesson material (SWF files) from the discs in the set. I want to move these lessons onto a web server and build a single client app. Something that just works as a generic container for these lessons.

Currently I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and Xamarin to build these containers. Unfortunately my strongest languages is vb.net and not C# though so It's taking a little getting used to. Does anyone have any tips or light they may be able to shed on the best way to go about getting a foot hold in this project?

I've pretty much decided I'm going to have to build this "container" from the ground up. Here is an example of the software I'm working with `http://184.168.83.81/Math7Demo/movie100.htm`

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have a same problem and I don't know how can i succedd this. Maybe we should try to using phonegap or similar tool. Please send to me message or comment here for solution approaching. Thx.

Comment: I was able to find a half-way solution. Using the Adobe Air plugin for Flash I was able to build an APK that worked on Android, and an IPA that worked on the iPhone/iPad. Although Because of the way my application is delivering content (pulling external SWF files from a server) it will not work for iOS. iOS restricts actionscript running in external SWF files. So I'll keep searching for another solution, but if you're just trying to build out to android I'd suggest using the Air plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a fellow developer who works with e-Learning for almost a decade, I'd say your best bet is to build the containers with PhoneGap, convert the SWFs with Google Swiffy and load them as HTML inside your app.

Comment: That would be a great idea, unfortunately Swiffy won't handle actionscript porting. I'm trying to make the case that it is time to abandon flash/AS all together and rebuild the software in a more modern way but the "Higher ups" are dead set against that. I was using Adobe Air to build out a version for mobile devices which worked great for Android (After converting the old AS2 to AS3) unfortunately because of iOS restrictions it does not look like that will be a viable solution for reaching out to Apple devices.

Comment: From my recent experiences, Swiffy handles AS2 porting quite good. Also, I've been able to hack the runtime and do some JavaScript magic. It would be even possible to control the Swiffy from iOS, calling JavaScript on the WebView. Hit me up if you need some help on the subject, I really think it's the easiest way, by a mileage.